# Node.JS: Watch a folder, modify new files, exclude program's modifications from fs.watch

Tags: node.js, fs, sharp

Currently, I am attempting to write a small Node.JS application that watches a folder for any new images, resizes them with the `sharp` npm package, then saves them to the same directory.

When I do this, `fs.watch(...)` fires off as if a new file has been added. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Code example:

```js
fs.watch(imgDir, (eventType, fileName) => {
    if(eventType == 'change') {
        sharp(inputPath)
            .resize({height: 720})
            .toFile(outputPath)
            .then((newFileInfo) => console.log(newFileInfo))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
});
```